# Is there any way to change the xy positions in scatter graph in core plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot, scatter

I am creating scatter graph, I need to change the x and y positions in scatter graph. Graph always starts with (0,0) positions but i need to show the starting points (7000, 800). Is there any way to change the x and y positions in scatter graph in core plot.

After showing the graph need to draw the line manually and get those values to search the properties.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to set the point where the co-ordinates meet you have to set the orthogonal co-ordinate decimal

```
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"800");
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"740000");
```

and for setting the range of values to be plotted set the visibleRange for both the axes

Answer (score 0):

These are features of the "plot space" in Core Plot. It defines the coordinate mapping between the plot area (basically the rectangle that contains all plot drawing) in data coordinates and the view in drawing coordinates. The `xRange` and `yRange` control the x and y range of the plot space, respectively.

The plot space converts coordinates in both directions—from data to view when drawing and from view to data when (for example) responding to touch events on a plot. See the [plot space docs](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_plot_space.html) for a list of the available coordinate conversion methods.